# Maximum possible size of encoded string

Tags: c#, string, encoding, datareader

What would be the maximum possible size of bytes for unknown encoded string with `X` characters?

I have buffer containing bits of stream. I want to make sure enough bits are loaded in buffer to read string before consuming the buffer.

Take a look at following code.

```
public async Task<string> ReadString(uint charCount)
{
    uint size = ??? ;

    // ensure remaining buffer is big enough 
    // to hold string with provided length
    // loads data from stream if buffer is 
    // smaller. does not throw exception 
    // if reached end of stream
    await EnsureBufferSize(size);

    var currentPos = _dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

    // Read string. Handles encoding
    // Throws exception if buffer is not big enough.
    var str = _dataReader.ReadString(charCount);

    // calculate number of bytes read
    BytesRead += currentPos - _dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

    return str;
}
```

I said unknown encoding because i dont want to make this too complicated. It doesnt matter if we fetch data more than needed. But it should never be less.

Comment: Why don't you just read until the end of string, no matter how long it actually is? `while (reader.Read())` (preferable in chunk sizes matching the expected encoding)

Comment: A "character" can be more than one byte, think Chinese characters in UTF-8.  Better to convert your text to bytes first, then add a block's worth of padding (8 bytes for DES, 16 bytes for AES).  If you are including an IV at the start of the encrypted bytes, then add another block size bytes for that.  You might also need space for an authentication check, such as HMAC + key, though those are sometimes handled separately if present.

Comment: A character can only be one or two bytes so the answer is 2X.

Comment: _"I said unknown encoding because i dont want to make this too complicated"_ -- not specifying the encoding makes the question unanswerable. Different encodings have different characteristics. All that said, this seems like classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The right way to decode bytes to text is to use a [Decoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a class that knows how to decode buffered streams of bytes without having to have all the bytes in hand when you start.